# "Partial update" message appears - why?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, updates, update-manager

Since about two days, a pop-up message about "partial update" from Software Updater keeps appearing on my screen (Ubuntu 20.04). It says that "some updates cannot be installed" and prompts me to do a partial update. If I skip this, I get an usual Software Updater window, that lists several packages regarding to NVIDIA drivers, which are unselectable and only one package is selected (I enclose the screenshot below). I did not perform the update yet because I don't know why this situation occurs and whether it is safe to do the "partial update" as the program suggests (won't it break anything in my system?).

The unselectable NVIDIA packages are all version 390.143-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, while my currently installed version is 390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1.

Could anybody advise, why this situation occurs and what should I do?

[image]

Below is the full output of `apt upgrade`, as requested in comments:

```
root@jarek-02:~# LANG=C apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common libetonyek-0.1-1 libfprint-2-tod1 libgconf-2-4 libjuh-java libjurt-java libllvm10 libllvm10:i386
  libllvm9 libllvm9:i386 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libneon27-gnutls liborcus-0.15-0 libreoffice-style-tango libridl-java libwps-0.4-4
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386 libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390
  libnvidia-encode-390:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386
  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-50-generic linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-objects-nvidia-390-5.8.0-50-generic
  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.8.0-50-generic nvidia-compute-utils-390 nvidia-dkms-390 nvidia-driver-390 nvidia-kernel-common-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390
  nvidia-utils-390 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
The following packages will be upgraded:
  flashplugin-installer gjs libgjs0g libnvidia-common-390 libxnvctrl0 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-notifier update-notifier-common
12 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 1576 kB of archives.
After this operation, 268 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue solved! I opened Synaptic hoping to get more information this way, marked all "upgradable" packages for upgrade and when I tried to apply this, Synaptic told me that besides installing all the new packages it needs to REMOVE `linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-49-generic`. It turned out I have two versions of this package installed: `linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-49-generic` and `linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-50-generic` (which was currently used). I don't know why version 49 did not get removed with all other files for version 49 that were removed during update. I removed the 49 version as Synaptic suggested, and when I re-launch the Software Updater, everything is correctly marked for update.